# Filtrar tablas segun variable foranea

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, estoy haciendo un proyecto de Laravel en el cual tengo una tabla llamada Plantas y otra llamada Comentarios. La historia es que quiero permitir que los usuarios escriban comentarios para preguntar sobre plantas. En relación a ello, quiero crear una vista en la cual pueda ver los comentarios filtrandolos segun sobre que planta se este hablando.

Aqui muestro el index.blade.php con la vista de los comentarios:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
<h1 class="text-center text-mute"> {{ __("Todos los comentarios") }} </h1>
@forelse($comentario as $c)
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h3>
Código del usuario: {{$c->usuario}}<br>
Código de la planta: {{ $c->planta }}
</h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
{{ $c->comentario }}
</div>
</div>
@empty
<div class="alert alert-danger">
{{ __("No hay ningún comentario sobre plantas en este momento") }}
</div>
@endforelse
</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Esta vista sera mencionada en el fichero web.php:

```
Route::get('/comentarios/{planta}','ComentarioController@show');
```

Y aqui el fichero ComentarioController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Comentario;
use App\plantas;

class ComentarioController extends Controller{
    public function show(Comentario $come){
        $comentario=$come->vegetal()->with('comentarios')->paginate(5);
        return view('comentarios.index', compact('planta','comentario'));
    }
}
```

Comentario.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comentario extends Model{
    protected $table = 'comentarios';

    protected $fillable = [
        'planta', 'usuario', 'comentario',
    ];

    public function vegetal(){
        return $this->belongsTo(plantas::class, 'planta');
    }

    public function usuario(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'usuario');
    }
}
```

Y la tabla Plantas.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class plantas extends Model{
    protected $table = 'plantas';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre', 'descripcion',
    ];

    public function comentarios(){
        return $this->hasMany(Comentario::class,'planta');
    }
}
```

Para mi prueba he preparado 2 plantas y a cada una le he preparado un comentario:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada uno de los titulo en la vista de las plantas incluye un enlace a la lista de comentarios de la planta, pero...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que habre hecho mal para que no se muestren los comentarios?

Edito, he probado a hacer una modificación en el fichero ComentarioController:

```
class ComentarioController extends Controller{
    public function show(Comentario $come){
        $comentario=$come->paginate(5);
        return view('comentarios.index', compact('planta','comentario'));
    }
}
```

Y adivinar el cambio:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Claramente el fallo esta en el fragmento "vegetal()->with('comentarios')->". Ahora la cuestión es descubrir que hago mal.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he solucionado, aunque me ha costado lo suyo.
Para empezar, he pasado la vista con los comentarios a la carpeta vegetal, que es donde tenia la vista de las plantas y lo he renombrado a detail.blade.php.
Luego he trasladado el codigo que tenia en ComentarioController a PlantasController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\plantas;

class PlantasController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $planta = Plantas::paginate(5);
        return view('vegetal.index', compact('planta'));
    }

    public function show(Plantas $planta){
    $comentario = $planta->comentarios()->with(['usuario'])->paginate(2);
    return view('vegetal.detail', compact('plantas','comentario'));
    }
}
```

Y he adaptado a todo esto la llamada en web.php:

```
Route::get('/comentarios/{planta}', 'PlantasController@show');
```

Y el resultado se ve mejor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]